# Presnt Continuous or Present Perfect Continuous?

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, present-perfect-progressive

Source:
https://english.elpais.com/economy-and-business/2023-03-16/blackrocks-larry-fink-does-not-rule-out-a-liquidity-crisis-after-svb-collapse.html

> Fink states that since the 2008 financial crisis, markets have been
> conditioned by “extraordinarily aggressive fiscal and monetary
> policies.” As a result of this, he says, inflation has risen to levels
> not seen since the 1980s. “To fight this inflation, the Federal
> Reserve in the past year has raised rates nearly 500 basis points.
> ***This is one price we’re already paying for years of easy money*** – and was the first domino to drop,” he explained.

Could the writer say "This is one price we have been paying for years of easy money"?

What is the difference (even if a slight) here?

My guess is using the Present Perfect Continuous would just stress the longness of the period. really I do not know, thank you.

Comment: we've already been paying for easy money. Anyway, the meaning is about the same. One stresses that it started in the past and continues now and the other is just what is happening now. I think this was taken from speaking, not writing.

Comment: Your version is almost a [garden-path sentence](https://www.thoughtco.com/garden-path-sentence-1690886) - "we have been paying for years" or "years of easy money"? The original stresses that "we have already started to pay for it", imp[lying that the 'starting' was recent.

Comment: @Lambie, Thank you for your reply, it is clear and helpful and answerd my question. It would be great if it was a full answer, but the link you provided was not what I asked about.